# Importing large inventory kills the mysql server

Tags: database, dataflow, inventory

I am using Magento data flow profiles for importing a very large inventory (has about 13000 products) and updating it three times a week.. i saw that after importing the products, the site is going slow each time and when i am running second update the data flow is working terribly slow it seems that it is killing the mysql server.

Any idea what is going on with this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the indexes to manual indexing instead of after save?

Comment: No i haven't tried this before.. dose this killing the db.

Comment: it creates a lot of extra load, better to turn it to manual and after the import run indexing trough the commandline if possible

$ php shell/indexer.php reindexall

Comment: I have updated the re indexing to manual update and I have also asked to our server rescue team to find the solution, could extending the resources will help ?

Comment: Extending resources could work, or for example move the MySQL to an external server. You'll have to do some experimenting with that. 

Please keep in mind that, if indexes are on manual, the changes you make in a product on the backend might not show up on frontend until you reindex

Comment: More resources AND mysql setting optimizations needed.

Answer (score 2):

The advice I can give is: Do not use the dataflow engine. It is slow and causes heavy load, as you noticed.

I have not found a better product-sync-engine than magmi: http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

The reasons:

1. imports directly into the database, not via the API
2. has many useful plugins that allow you to directly link configurable products, import crossselling, index on-the-fly...

Changing from dataflow to magmi is not a big problem as the csv format is nearly the same.

Comment: @ravisoni Glad I could help :)

Comment: magmi is great but it definitely need a developer to babysit it.  You can really screw up your store otherwise, particularly if you don't carefully test updates.